# How to delete VF Page's tab from package which is not pushed on exchange, which is yet to be reviewed . How to delete

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, visualforce-component, tab

We have package created which includes one test "Tab" . in VF page. We dont want this tab to be sent along with package.

When We attempt to delete this, It somehow not allowing or not seeing option to delte.

Can you please guide or let me know steps how we can delete

Regards
Ashish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Package Version Has Never Been Installed

Log a case in the [Partner Community](https://partners.salesforce.com/) and request that the package be rolled back to a Beta version. You will need to roll all the way back to the version that first introduced the items to remove, which requires all later versions to have been never installed in any org. This technique will allow you to delete the item from the package, since you're effectively undoing the "managed" attribute of everything in the package from that version on.

## Package Version Has Been Installed At Least Once

To enable the ability to [delete packaged components from your package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm):

> - Log a case in the [Partner Community](https://partners.salesforce.com/) to enable Component Deletion in your packaging org.
> - Deleting Visualforce pages and global Visualforce components from a managed package requires a two-stage process, because their behavior differs from the behavior of public Apex classes and public Visualforce components. Upon package upgrade in a subscriber org, Visualforce pages and global Visualforce components that you've deleted aren't removed. A "Delete" button or link is made available to the org's administrators, but many orgs continue using obsolete pages and components. However, public Apex classes and public Visualforce components are deleted as part of the upgrade process. If you delete pages and components without performing this two-stage procedure, Salesforce can’t warn you when your later deletion of public classes and components would break your subscribers’ obsolete pages and components.
>
> If you’re deleting a Visualforce page or global Visualforce component that refers to or uses public Apex classes or public Visualforce components, perform the deletion steps in this order.
>
> 1. Stage one: Remove references.
>
>    a. To remove all references to public Apex classes or public Visualforce components, edit your Visualforce page or global Visualforce component .
>
>    b. Upload your new package version.
>
>    c. Push the stage-one upgrade to your subscribers.
> 2. Stage two: Delete your obsolete pages or components.
>
>    a. Delete your Visualforce page or global Visualforce component.
>
>    b. Optionally, delete other related components and classes.
>
>    c. Upload your new package version.
>
>    d. Push the stage-two upgrade to your subscribers.

Comment: Is there simpler way ? this seems like too many things to be done for simple update. Just a thought. This package is only installed on another dev instance by us only for testing . Not rolled out yet all

Comment: No. Not once you have created a managed version and uploaded it